# Como usar un ID de un formulario para hacer una consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el código completo.

```html
<div class="right_col" role="main">

 <div class="x_panel">
  <div class="x_title">
   <h2>Gestión de casos</h2>
   <div class="row">
    <?php if (!isset($_SESSION["Electronica"])) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo URL ?>caso/nuevo" data-href="" data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></i>&nbsp;Nuevo caso</a>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="x_content">


   <br />
   <div class="row table-responsive">
    <table id="listas" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
     <thead class="tableH">
      <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nº CUENTA</th>
       <th>CLIENTE</th>
       <th>NOMBRE DE CONTACTO</th>
       <th>TIPO DE FALLA</th>
       <th>FECHA </th>
       <th>ESTADO</th>


       <?php if (!isset($_SESSION["Monitoreo"])) { ?>
      <th>OPCIONES</th>
      <?php } ?> 
      </tr>
     </thead>




     <tbody>
                             <tr>
      <?php foreach($caso as $p) { ?>
       <th><?php echo $p->id ?></th>
       <td><?php echo $p->ncuenta ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p->nombre ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p->nombredec?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p->falla?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p->fecha?></td>
       

       <td class="estado"><?php if ($p->estado == 'En proceso') { ?>
        <span class="label label-warning" style=""><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span></td>
        <?php }else if($p->estado == 'Suspendido'){ ?>
        <span class="label label-danger" ><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span>
        <?php }else if ($p->estado == 'Solucionado'){ ?>
                                <span class="label label-success" ><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION["Monitoreo"])) { ?>
     <td style="text-align: center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" id="" onclick="Tcaso(<?=$p->id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar</a></td>
     <?php } ?>
       
                        </tr>
      <?php } ?>

      
        </tbody>

     </table>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  




<div class="modal fade" id="modalT" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">

   <div class="modal-header" >
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="" style="color: white "><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Modificar caso</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="modal-body">
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo URL ?>caso/modificarCaso" >
     <div class="form-group row">

      <label for="telefono" class="col-md-1 control-label">Nº Cuenta</label>
              <div class="col-md-2" autofocus disabled>

               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input  soloNum" id="ncuentaca" name="ncuentaca" autofocus disabled>




               <!-- <?php foreach($clienter as $cli){ ?>
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input  soloNum" id="ncuentaca" name="ncuentaca" value="<?php echo $cli->idcliente ?>"><?php echo $cli->ncuenta ?>

                

               <?php } ?> -->
              </div>

              <label for="cliente" class="col-md-1 control-label">Cliente</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" name="nombreca" id="nombreca"  autofocus disabled>
              </div>

             


              <?php echo $p->id ?>


            

              

              
              <label for="documento" class="col-md-1 control-label">Dirección</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" id="direccionca" name="direccionca" disabled="">
              </div>

             
              
            </div>

            

            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

            <input type="hidden" name="idcliente" id="idcliente">

            <br>

             <div class="form-group row">

              <label for="telefono" class="col-md-1 control-label">Teléfono</label>
              <div class="col-md-2" autofocus disabled>
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input  soloNum" id="telefonoca" name="telefonoca" autofocus disabled>
              </div>

              <label for="telefono" class="col-md-1 control-label">Ciudad</label>
              <div class="col-md-2">
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input " id="ciudadca" name="ciudadca" class="" autofocus disabled>
              </div>

              <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label">Nombre de contacto</label >
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" name="nombredecca" id="nombredecca" autofocus disabled>
              </div>

            </div>

             <div class="form-group row">
              <br>

              <?php 

            $fecha1 = date("Y-m-d");
            
            ?>

              <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label">Responsable</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" id="resca" name="resca" readonly >
              </div>

               <label for="cliente" class="col-md-1 control-label">Fecha</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" id="fecca" name="fecca" readonly>
              </div>

              </div>

            <br>
              <br>
            <div class="form-group row">
               
              <label for="nombredect" class="col-md-1 control-label">Falla</label >
              <div class="col-md-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm input" name="fallaca" id="fallaca" autofocus disabled>

              </div>

              

            </div>


             <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label">Descripción</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control input-sm input" name="descripcionca" id="descripcionca" autofocus disabled></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

           <div class="form-group row">

            

        <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label">Seguimiento</label>
        <?php foreach($casos as $y) { ?>

        <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo $y->seguimiento?></label >






            <?php  } ?>






           </div>





<br>
             <div class="form-group row">

            <label for="nombredect" class="col-md-1 control-label">Estado</label >
              <div class="col-md-2">
             <SELECT name="estadoca" id="estadoca" class="form-control input-sm input" onchange="if(this.value=='Solucionado') {document.getElementById('solucionado').disabled = false} else {document.getElementById('solucionado').disabled = true} ">
             <OPTION value="En proceso" selected>En proceso</OPTION>
             <OPTION value="Suspendido">Suspendido</OPTION>
             <OPTION value="Solucionado">Solucionado</OPTION>
             
             </SELECT>
 

              </div>

            

          </div>

         

            <div class="form-group row">

             <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label">Seguimiento</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control input-sm input" name="seguimiento" id="seguimiento"></textarea>
              </div>


              <label for="cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label">Solucionado</label >
              <div class="col-md-3">
                 <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control input-sm input" name="solucionado" id="solucionado" required disabled></textarea>
              </div>



            </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
     <?php if (isset($_SESSION["Administrador"]) == 1) { ?>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"  name="deleteeca">
     Borrar</button>
        <?php } ?>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="" name="enviarCa">Guardar</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
</div>








<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['caso'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['caso'];
 unset($_SESSION['caso']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['casos'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['casos'];
 unset($_SESSION['casos']);
}





?>
```

Controlador

```html
public function index(){
  
  $caso = new Caso();
  $caso = $caso->ListarCaso();



  $casos = new Caso();
  $casos = $casos->ListarSeguimiento();

  $cliente = new Cliente();
  $clienter = $cliente->ListarClientes();






  include APP.'view/_templates/header.php';
  include APP.'view/caso/index.php';
  include APP.'view/_templates/footer.php';
 }
```

Modelo

```html
public function ListarSeguimiento(){


     $sql = "SELECT idseguimiento, seguimiento , idcaso FROM seguimiento c join caso p on c.idcaso = p.id where idcaso = idcaso";
     $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
     $query->execute();

     return $query->fetchAll();

   }
```

Ajax

```js
function Tcaso(id){ 
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{'id':id},
    dataType:'json',
    url: uri + "/caso/mostrarCasos",
   }).done(function(respuesta){
    $("#id").val(respuesta.id);
    $("#idcliente").val(respuesta.idcliente);
    $("#ncuentaca").val(respuesta.ncuenta);
    $("#nombreca").val(respuesta.nombre);
    $("#direccionca").val(respuesta.direccion);
    $("#telefonoca").val(respuesta.telefono);
    $("#ciudadca").val(respuesta.ciudad);
    $("#nombredecca").val(respuesta.nombredec);
                $("#fallaca").val(respuesta.falla);
                $("#descripcionca").val(respuesta.descripcion);
                $("#resca").val(respuesta.responsable);
                $("#fecca").val(respuesta.fecha);
                $("#estadoca").val(respuesta.estado);
                $("#solucionado").val(respuesta.solucion);
    
    $("#modalT").modal();

    
  
   });
  }
```

Así como esta el código me trae los seguimientos de mi tabla casos , pero los trae todos , lo que quiero es que cuando abra el modal me muestre solo los casos de ese id , para eso necesito enviar el id que esta en el input para compararlo en el modelo y traer el resultado , pero no me quiere dar así.

Comment: seria bueno que muestres el codigo completo de como obtienes dicho id y lo pasas  a : ListarSeguimiento($id)

Comment: Solo estaba probando poniendo  $id= $_POST['id']; arriba de la función $casos = new Caso();
  $casos = $casos->ListarSeguimiento($id);

Comment: Así es como lo estaba ensayando no me da por eso pregunto de que otra forma puedo hacerlo

Comment: podrias poner el codigo completo tanto del formulario como del codigo php.

Comment: te recomiendo poner un alert despues de donde declaras tu funcion.. algo asi: function Tcaso(id){ alert("este es mi id"+id);.......}

Comment: para saber si efectivamente obtienes el id....en caso de que no observes el id en el alert...sabras que no estas obteniendo el mismo

Comment: si estoy obteniendo el id , mas sin embargo la función no lo esta resiviendo

Comment: ya tambien lo intente poniendolo en otra función aparte del index , como en el mostrarCasos donde muestro la información del caso , y aun asì no funciona

Comment: te recomiendo revisar :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310145/javascript-getting-value-of-a-td-with-id-name

Comment: te puede servir y guiar

Comment: y al momento de construir tu tabla html asumo que traes el id, ese id debes previamente asignarlo en donde llamas a la funcion

Comment: <td class="text-center">
                                    <!--BTN EDITAR-->
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="consultarAgencia('{{ agencia_carga.id }}');">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>

Comment: si te fijas en este caso le asigno directamente el id y llamo a una funcion consultarAgencia la cual recibe el id,,,

Comment: ahora debes hacerlo en php, porque yo uso otro lenguaje.. python